# Building Android 4.0 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: android, macos, build

I got the below error when I tried to build Android 4.0 on Mac OS X Lion.

```
Please install the 10.5 SDK on this machine at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
external/qemu/Makefile.android:82: *** Aborting the build..  Stop.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? 
Do I need to install Mac OS X 10.5 SDK on Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get Xcode 3 [link](https://developer.apple.com/devcente...os_sdk_4.3.dmg)

and after go to this web site [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110318050811544)

Answer (score 2):

you have to install the sdk 10.5 of Mac [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/VVubaS56/MacOSX105.html?refurl=d1url)

Comment: This link works, compared to the selected answer above, whose link has expired / been removed.

Answer (score 1):

On newer version of Xcode (newer than Xcode 3) the SDK is under:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/

I changed the Makefile.android file to point to the right one.

It passed from this error, but I got some other further. Still working on it.

Answer (score -1):

I have compiled Android for Snow Leopard, Maybe these steps will help. They can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464438/building-android-4-0-on-mac-os-x-lion).